# Sublime text is not committing to clipboard history

Tags: sublime-text-3

OS: MacOS

All my clipboard history softwares ignore any text I copy from sublime text.

I am stable able to copy text from Sublime Text and paste it in other apps. It's just that the clipboard history software does not register text i copied from Sublime Text.

I am assuming sublime text has some privacy mechanism to prevent other softwares from reading contents of its clipboard.

Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 1):

Many users experience issues copying and pasting in sublime text when other applications interfere with its ability to read the clipboard.

### Windows Applications

**Webroot**

It appears **Webroot SecureAnywhere** will sandbox the editor as part of its identity protection functionality. This will prevent the editor's access to the clipboard. In order to prevent webroot from interfering, navigate to **WebRoot Secure Anywhere**’s "Protected Applications" screen. From there, you can locate **SublimeText** in the list of protected applications and change "Deny" to "Allow.

**RealVNC**

One user reported having issues with RealVNC's clipboard lock preventing Sublime Text from reading the clipboard. Try closing RealVNC to see if the problem persists.

### Reset Keymap

If you setup different keyboard shortcuts, we can try to reset the user keymap configuration to see if that solves the issue. You can access the file by clicking on **Preferences** on the menubar, then by clicking on **Key Bindings.** Alternatively, the file is located here:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-keymap
```

If the file is present and has entries in it, make a backup of the file by copying and pasting the file to another folder on your computer. Once the backup is made, we can modify the original file. Change the file contents to the following:

```
[

]
```

Restart Sublime Text to see if the copy and paste functionality is restored.

### Clean/Portable Installation

We can also try to load the [portable version](https://download.sublimetext.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%203211%20x64.zip) of Sublime Text to see if a clean installation works. This will rule out any configurations made to sublime that could be causing the issue. If the problem still persists in the portable version. Open the console by going to the menubar at the top and clicking **View**. Then click on the **Show Console** option. The console will verify if Sublime Text is having errors. It will show things like the following when you try to copy/paste:

```
Unable to extract text from clipboard
```

or

```
Unable to get CF_TEXT from clipboard
```

If these errors are not present, there could be another application locking the clipboard that was not already mentioned. Definitely check antivirus software, and other software that exclusively locks the clipboard.

Comment: sorry should have clarified, I'm on mac